# Cite in square brackets

Tags: citing, natbib

I need to create square brackets citations in headlines of theorems. 
Below I'm enclosing photo and preambole.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

\let\memoldbibsection\bibsection
\let\bibsection\relax
\usepackage[nobysame]{amsrefs}
\let\bibsection\memoldbibsection 


\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[right=2.7cm,left=3.5cm, top=2.7cm, bottom=2.5cm,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}


\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\let\lll\relax


\makeindex


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}


\makeatletter

\renewcommand\PrintNames@a[4]{%
    \PrintSeries{\name}
        {#1}
        {}{ i \set@othername}
        {,}{ \set@othername}
        {}{ i \set@othername}
        {#2}{#4}{#3}%
}



%Rysunki w TikZ 
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

%Styl rozdzialow
\setlength\midchapskip{10pt}
\makechapterstyle{Vincent}{
\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
\renewcommand\printchaptername{}
\renewcommand\chapnamefont{\Large\scshape}
\renewcommand\printchapternum{\chapnamefont \@chapapp \space \thechapter \centering}
\renewcommand\printchapternonum{\hrule\vskip\midchapskip}
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\Huge\scshape\centering}
\renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\nobreak\vskip\midchapskip\hrule\vskip\midchapskip}
\renewcommand\afterchaptertitle{\par\vskip\midchapskip\hrule\nobreak\vskip\afterchapskip}
}

%Styl sekcji
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}
                                                                     {\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\large\scshape}}%\bfseries}}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}  
\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname .\hspace{2.5mm}}

%Styl subsekcji
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection {subsection}{2}
                                                                     {\z@}%
                                   {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                   {-0.5em}%
                                   {\scshape\raggedright}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}

%Styl naglowkow
\makepagestyle{Ada}
\makeoddhead{Ada}{\scshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}
\makeheadrule{Ada}{148mm}{0.5pt} %\headwidth
\makepsmarks{Ada}{%
\def\chaptermark##1{%
\markright{%
\ifnum\c@secnumdepth > \m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\fi
\fi
##1}}{}}
\nouppercaseheads

%Styl spisu treści
\renewcommand*{\cftchapteraftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\@dotsep}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}
\renewcommand*{\cftparskip}{2pt}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{Vincent}
\pagestyle{Ada}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}

%styl podpisu
\newcommand{\signaturespace}[2]{%
  % #1 = width of the dotted line
  % #2 = legend
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
  \hspace*{0pt}%
  \cleaders\hbox{\kern.1pt.\kern.1pt}\hskip#1\relax
  \hspace*{0pt}%
  \\[2pt]
  \scriptsize#2
  \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

%indeks

\newtheoremstyle{break}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {\itshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{}%

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{definicja}{Definicja}[section]
\newtheorem{przyklad}{Przykład}[section]
\newtheorem{oznaczenie}{Oznaczenie}
\newtheorem{wlasnosc}{Własność}[section]
\newtheorem{wlasnosci}{Własności}[section]
\newtheorem{uwaga}{Uwaga}[chapter]


\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{twierdzenie}{Twierdzenie}[section]
\newtheorem{lemat}{Lemat}[section]
\newtheorem{wniosek}{Wniosek}[chapter]
\newtheorem{stwierdzenie}{Stwierdzenie}[chapter]

\newcommand{\mabs}[1]{|#1|}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\newcommand{\babs}[1]{\bigl|#1\bigr|}
\newcommand{\Babs}[1]{\Bigl|#1\Bigr|}
\newcommand{\bgabs}[1]{\biggl|#1\biggr|}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\|#1\right\|}
\newcommand{\bnorm}[1]{\bigl\|#1\bigr\|}
\newcommand{\mnorm}[1]{\|#1\|}
\newcommand{\set}[2]{\left\{#1: #2\right\}}
\newcommand{\bset}[2]{\bigl\{#1: #2\bigr\}}
\newcommand{\Bset}[2]{\Bigl\{#1: #2\Bigr\}}
\newcommand{\absp}[1]{\!\!\left\bracevert\! #1\! \right\bracevert\!\!}
\newcommand{\zdef}{{\mathrel{\mathop:}=}}
\newcommand{\defz}{{=\mathrel{\mathop:}}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\re}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cl}{cl}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\conv}{conv}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lin}{lin}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diam}{diam}
\DeclareMathOperator{\meas}{meas}

\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace\labelsep #1}


%dowód od nowej lini 
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\mbox{}\\*
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{definicja}[{\cite[str.~71]{Doman}}]
Niech dany będzie zbiór $k$ punktów na płaszczyźnie, tzn. $\mathcal{K}_0=\{P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_k\}$. Kreśląc wszystkie możliwe okręgi i proste z danych punktów oraz wyznaczając ich części wspólne otrzymamy nowe punkty $P_{k+1}, P_{k+2}, \ldots, P_{k+l}$, gdzie $l \in \mathbb{N}$.  \\
Zbiór złożony z punktów $P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_k$ oraz z punktów $P_{k+1}, P_{k+2}, \ldots, P_{k+l}$ nazywa się zbiorem punktów konstruowalnych i oznacza się go jako $\mathcal{K}_1$. 
\end{definicja}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
\markboth{Bibliografia}{Bibliografia}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografia}

      \bib{Doman}{book}{
      title={Wykład z geometrii elementarnej},
      author={R. Doman},
      date={1998},
      place={Poznań},
      publisher={Wydawnictwo Naukowe UAM},
    }



\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}


\renewcommand{\indexname}{Skorowidz symboli}
\idxlayout{columns=3}
\printindex[sym]


\renewcommand{\indexname}{Skorowidz}
\idxlayout{columns=2, unbalanced=false}
\renewcommand{\indexspace}{\par\vspace{15pt}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a *full* yet *minimal* compilable code that we can play with?

Comment: It should be worked

Comment: (i'm almost certain that this has been answered before, but my browser won't allow me to search.)  one solution is to hide the brackets so that they won't be interpreted as an optional argument -- place a pair of braces around the brackets that are to appear in the output.  since you want only the braces, not parentheses that are ordinarily inserted with `amsthm`, you probably should use a starred theorem environment that allows you to specify the entire theorem header in the input.

Comment: I'm greatful but I don't want to make it to theorem. 
it should be citation not theorem.

Answer (score 3):

I have added manually defined theorem style and the same was given below:

```
\newtheoremstyle{bfnote}% name of the style to be used.
{9pt}% measure of space to leave above the theorem.
{9pt}% measure of space to leave below the theorem.
{}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem.
{}% measure of space to indent.
{\bfseries}% name of head font.
{\\}% punctuation between head and body.
{0.5em}% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space.
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ #3}}% manually specify head.

\theoremstyle{bfnote}
\newtheorem{definicja}{Definicja}[section]
\newtheorem{przyklad}{Przyklad}[section]
\newtheorem{oznaczenie}{Oznaczenie}
\newtheorem{wlasnosc}{Wlasnosc}[section]
\newtheorem{wlasnosci}{Wlasnosci}[section]
\newtheorem{uwaga}{Uwaga}[chapter]
```

Comment: This solution don't give full answer, because I would like to get format [zob. 2 str. 17]